# Get output in some of collection class which contain all seven days schedule time

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my query with `sql server` ,

```
SELECT     dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProfessionalIDF, 
                dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProviderIDF,
                dbo.tbCareProvider.CareProviderName, 
                dbo.tbCitizen.FirstName + ' ' + dbo.tbCitizen.MiddleName + ' ' + dbo.tbCitizen.FamilyName AS CareProfessionalName,  
                dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheeduleWeekDays, 
                dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheduleStartTime, dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheduleEndTime, 

                    dbo.tbScheduleDetail.ScheduleStartDate, dbo.tbScheduleDetail.ScheduleEndDate          
FROM         dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbScheduleDetail ON dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheduleDetailIDF = dbo.tbScheduleDetail.ScheduleDetailIDP INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCareProvider ON dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProviderIDF = dbo.tbCareProvider.CareProviderIDP INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCareProfessional ON dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProfessionalIDF = dbo.tbCareProfessional.CareProfessionalIDP INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCitizen ON dbo.tbCareProfessional.CitizenIDF = dbo.tbCitizen.CitizenIDP
WHERE     (dbo.tbScheduleDetail.IsActive = 1) and CareProviderIDF=4 order by CareProfessionalIDF
```

Output :

[image]

At last i want out put like

so i have split scheduleweekdays by ',' than where i get true, for that index i want to store strattime and endtime in `day[index]`

Here i take only one of combination 
(CareProfessionalIDF=11) i got 4 row and store time

```
====================================
         StartTime TO EndTime    
====================================
 day[0] = 00:00TO22:00
 day[1] = 00:00TO22:00
 day[2] = 04:15TO19:15
 day[3] = 04:00TO20:00 
 day[4] = 08:00TO15:00
 day[5] = ""
 day[6] = ""
```

So how can i store data like this for all combination .
For that which `data structure` i have to use ?

Comment: why do you want to group by? what are you looking to sum or count?

Comment: `@Sharvari Dave` who stop you to do so..?.go ahead..

Comment: Hello wait a minute I will edit question ..

Comment: Is it possible with store procedure ????

Comment: ...I can't say I totally understand what the structure here is, but this should probably be normalized. That field that contains 7 different pieces of data ought to be broken up, either into 1 column per day or into another table with 1 row per day. As a rule, when it comes to databases, it is almost *always* easier to put things back together than to pull them apart.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Groub by`, you need to either **include all** columns that you select from  in the Group By Clause or you need to `aggregate` the remaining columns, e.g.

Query with Aggregate

```
SELECT  FieldToGroup ,
        SUM(FieldToSum)
FROM    TableName
GROUP BY FieldToGroup
```

Query with all fields grouped

```
SELECT  FieldToGroup ,
        Field2ToGroup
FROM    TableName
GROUP BY FieldToGroup ,
        Field2ToGroup
```

Comment: How is the second query any different than just a `SELECT` without `GROUP BY`?

Comment: `@christiandev` sorry for previous post , i have update it plz find edited post.

Comment: @jpmc26, when you add Group By, the result is grouped.

Comment: But you're grouping by *all* the output columns... which is the same as grouping by none of them. ...Unless it eliminates duplicates? If a candidate key is in the result set, there aren't even any duplicates to eliminate.

Comment: @jpmc26, exactly, if you have duplicate data, then they would be grouped.  The point I am making is that you must either group by all or aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Select Sum(CareProfessionalIDF) as CareProfessionalID ,...... from {
-- Your query

} group by CareProfessionalIDF ,......
```

Comment: `@Jodha` sorry for previous post , i have update it plz find edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this -

```
SELECT  sd.CareProfessionalIDF
    ,   CareProviderIDF = MAX(sd.CareProviderIDF)
    ,   ScheeduleWeekDays = MAX(sts.ScheeduleWeekDays)
    ,   ScheduleTimeSlotIDP = MAX(sts.ScheduleTimeSlotIDP)
    ,   ScheduleStartTime = MAX(sts.ScheduleStartTime)
    ,   ScheduleEndTime = MAX(sts.ScheduleEndTime)
    ,   CareProviderName = MAX(cp.CareProviderName)
    ,   CareProfessionalName = MAX(c.FirstName + ' ' + c.MiddleName + ' ' + c.FamilyName)
    ,   ScheduleFor = MAX(sd.ScheduleFor)
    ,   ScheduleStartDate = MAX(sd.ScheduleStartDate)
    ,   ScheduleEndDate = MAX(sd.ScheduleEndDate)
    ,   SplitIntervalStart = MAX(sts.SplitIntervalStart)
    ,   SplitIntervalEnd = MAX(sts.SplitIntervalEnd)
    ,   SlotInterval = MAX(sts.SlotInterval)
    ,   IsActive = MAX(sd.IsActive)
    ,   IsSplitSchedule = MAX(sts.IsSplitSchedule)
FROM dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot sts
JOIN dbo.tbScheduleDetail sd ON sts.ScheduleDetailIDF = sd.ScheduleDetailIDP
JOIN dbo.tbCareProvider cp ON sd.CareProviderIDF = cp.CareProviderIDP
JOIN dbo.tbCareProfessional cp2 ON sd.CareProfessionalIDF = cp2.CareProfessionalIDP
JOIN dbo.tbCitizen c ON cp2.CitizenIDF = c.CitizenIDP
WHERE sts.IsActive = 1
    AND CareProviderIDF = 4
GROUP BY sd.CareProfessionalIDF
```

Comment: `@Devart` sorry for previous post , i have update it plz find edited post.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. Can you provide a more a detailed description?

Comment: i want day[7] array for each unique `CareProfessionalIDF` above i gave ex with `CareProfessionalIDF=11` and make `array[]` same like i want for CareProfessionalIDF=10 ,CareProfessionalIDF=13 ....
At last,
I need one collection like
`<10,array[7]>,
<11,array[7]>,
<13,array[7]>`

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

```
SELECT  dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProfessionalIDF ,
        dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProviderIDF ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheeduleWeekDays ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheduleTimeSlotIDP ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheduleStartTime ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheduleEndTime ,
        dbo.tbCareProvider.CareProviderName ,
        dbo.tbCitizen.FirstName + ' ' + dbo.tbCitizen.MiddleName + ' '
        + dbo.tbCitizen.FamilyName AS CareProfessionalName ,
        dbo.tbScheduleDetail.ScheduleFor ,
        dbo.tbScheduleDetail.ScheduleStartDate ,
        dbo.tbScheduleDetail.ScheduleEndDate ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.SplitIntervalStart ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.SplitIntervalEnd ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.SlotInterval ,
        dbo.tbScheduleDetail.IsActive ,
        dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.IsSplitSchedule
FROM    dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbScheduleDetail ON dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.ScheduleDetailIDF = dbo.tbScheduleDetail.ScheduleDetailIDP
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbCareProvider ON dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProviderIDF = dbo.tbCareProvider.CareProviderIDP
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbCareProfessional ON dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProfessionalIDF = dbo.tbCareProfessional.CareProfessionalIDP
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbCitizen ON dbo.tbCareProfessional.CitizenIDF = dbo.tbCitizen.CitizenIDP
WHERE   ( dbo.tbScheduleTimeSlot.IsActive = 1 )
        AND CareProviderIDF = 4 ORDER BY dbo.tbScheduleDetail.CareProfessionalIDF
```